# Issue when decoding aerospike's msgpack in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aerospike, msgpack

I'm trying to decode bins' data returned by an aerospike get query using nodejs but i keep getting data containing weird `\u0003` unicode characters.

I have stored the data in aerospike using a simple script much like the default example

```
'use strict';

const Aerospike = require('aerospike');

const key = new Aerospike.Key('test', 'test_set', '1234');
const client = Aerospike.client({hosts: '127.0.0.1'});
const bins = {
    test: {
        '123': '1', 
        '456': '1'
    }
};

client.connect((err) => {
    if(err) return console.error('Could not connect to aerospike', err);
    return client.put(key, bins, (err) => {
        if(err) return console.error('Error when inserting data', err);
        console.log('Record has been written');
    });
});
```

I then retrieve the key bins and their associated values.

`82a403313233a20331a403343536a20331` is the hex content of the bin `test` that we previously inserted.

When decoded using various nodejs msgpack libraries:

- https://github.com/mcollina/msgpack5
- https://github.com/pgriess/node-msgpack
- https://github.com/kawanet/msgpack-lite

I always get the same result which is not what i inserted in the first place:

```
{
    test: {
        '\u0003123': '\u00031',
        '\u0003456': '\u00031'
    }
}
```

All the msgpack libraries i tried seem to match the msgpack spec described [here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) which means that Aerospike uses an alternate format based on msgpack.

If that's the case where can i find this alternate protocol ?

Answer (score 1):

The [wire protocol](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/dev_reference/wire_protocol.html) isn't based on msgpack.

[CDT](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt.html) bins are encoded with msgpack with [custom extensions](https://github.com/aerospike/msgpack).

### Edit

The extension is used to express how the map is ordered, this could be [unordered, key ordered, or key-value ordered](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/blob/master/as/src/base/particle_map.c#L127-L128). See [here](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/client/src/com/aerospike/client/util/Unpacker.java#L162) for how the Java client unpacks this information.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i already checked it out previously but there is no documentation available, the API & wiki link doesn't seem to work anymore (http://redmine.msgpack.org/projects/msgpack/wiki) and there is no mention of a custom implementation. Is there somewhere i can find the specification of these custom extensions ?

Comment: Are you trying to decode all bins with msgpack or just cdt bins. The types in your sample aren't cdts so they aren't packed with msgmack.

Comment: Ah, missed that inner definition. Curious, what is this needed for? Will see if I can find information about the extension.

Comment: The `test` bin contains a map and if i'm not mistaken it is converted to a CDT of type `map` by the node aerospike client.

Comment: Okay great, i'll wait for your reponse then. Thank you very much !

Comment: Sure, soonest will be tomorrow.

Comment: Updated the answer with the information I could find.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you very much, i'll take a look at it as soon as i can.